# False Positives with Face recognition

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition, torch, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN trained upon the images (cropped faces) of Mark Ruffalo. For my positive class I have around 200 images and for the negative datapoints I have sampled 200 random faces.

The model has a high recall but a very low precision. How could I increase the precision ?Also I am constrained by the number of positive images that I have. I am ready to compromise the recall in this tradeoff.

I have tried increasing the number of negative samples but that introduces a form of bias and the model starts classifying everything as negative to attain a local optima.

I have based my CNN upon overfeat:

```
local features = nn.Sequential()

features:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(3, 96, 11, 11))
features:add(nn.ReLU())
features:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

features:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(96, 256, 5, 5))
features:add(nn.ReLU())
features:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

features:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(256, 512, 3, 3))
features:add(nn.ReLU())
features:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

-- 24x24x512
features:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(512, 1024, 3, 3))
features:add(nn.ReLU())
features:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

--11x11x1024
features:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(1024, 1024, 3, 3))
features:add(nn.ReLU())
features:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))

-- 1.3. Create Classifier (fully connected layers)
local classifier = nn.Sequential()
classifier:add(nn.View(1024*4*4))
classifier:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
classifier:add(nn.Linear(1024*4*4, 3072))
classifier:add(nn.Threshold(0, 1e-6))

classifier:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
classifier:add(nn.Linear(3072, 4096))
classifier:add(nn.Threshold(0, 1e-6))

classifier:add(nn.Linear(4096, noutputs))




model = nn.Sequential():add(features):add(classifier)
```

Kindly Help

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the raw output of the CNN instead of taking the sign() of the output node (since it is a positive and negative class I assume there is only one output in the range `[-1,1]`).

For instance, for one sample, the output could be `[0.9]` indicating that the positive class should be picked. But if you play with this values, you can find a specific `threshold` value, *hopefully*, that gives you the precision you need. In other words, if you find that anything greater than `[-0.35]` should actually be chosen as the positive class because it gived you better precision, then `-0.35` should be your `threshold` value.

This is where [ROC analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) comes in handy.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I do have output in the form of a continuous range. The issue is that this ideal scenario is not followed. The false positives cannot be distinguished from the true positives no matter what( in terms of the functional value for each class).

Comment: In that case, it seems like it is a problem of feature extraction. You need a better face image representation. Doing `PCA` is easy and [there is a lot of documentation](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf) about it. It is a good alternative if you have controlled illumination in the images and little variation in pose and facial expression.  Have you tried that? PCA for face recognition is also known as `eigenfaces`. Are you doing any feature extraction/representation currently?

Comment: I have tried fisherfaces and lbp. Without aligning the faces they fail miserably. However after aligning the same issue of false positives come up!